# g++ says it can't load a library that exists

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I have a case where g++ refuses to load a library. I have a file deps/lib/libskgxp11.so. I place `-L deps/lib` and `-lskgxp11` on the g++ command. I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libskgxp11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My overall purpose is to get a test to run with gtest that connects to Oracle, executes select * from dual, and compares the result.

I have the following in Makefile:

```
g++ -m32 -o $(test_target) -L deps/lib -Wl,--start-group $(dep_libs) -lpthread -ldl -lskgxpr -lskgxp11 -locrb11 -locr11 -lhasgen11 -lnnz11 -lskgxn2 -locrutl11 -lclntsh $(test_objects) -Wl,--end-group
```

I have used the same basic sequence of -Wl,--start group, all dependent static libraries, all dependent shared libaries, all object files, -Wl,--end-group on other projects and it works just fine.

Notice the -m32, we're doing everything in 32 bits right now. All the other shared libraries load fine, and are all in the same dir:

```
ls deps/lib/libskgxpr.so deps/lib/libskgxp11.so deps/lib/libocrb11.so deps/lib/libocr11.so deps/lib/libhasgen11.so deps/lib/libnnz11.so deps/lib/libskgxn2.so deps/lib/libocrutl11.so deps/lib/libclntsh.so | cat

deps/lib/libclntsh.so
deps/lib/libhasgen11.so
deps/lib/libnnz11.so
deps/lib/libocr11.so
deps/lib/libocrb11.so
deps/lib/libocrutl11.so
deps/lib/libskgxn2.so
deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
```

I do notice one strange thing, it seems that the following group of libraries are somehow related:

```
deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
```

They each seem to define the same functions. The other 4 seem to depend on libskgxp11, in the sense that if I link any of the other 4 by themselves with a -l option, g++ complains that it can't load libskgxp11.

I have a command sequence that can tell me for each remaining function I need to get from some shared lib, which shared lib(s) contain it. It gives the following:

```
skgxpcdel
  deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
skgxpcini_with_stats
  deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
skgxpcon_with_stats
  deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
...
```

where skgxpcdel is a func I'm looking for. All of the outstanding functions I need give the same list of the same 5 libraries.

If I run objdump -T on the 5 libraries, they all seem to be 32-bit shared libs, I don't see anything special about the one that doesn't load compared to the ones that do:

```
for i in deps/lib/libskgxp11.so deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so deps/lib/libskgxpd.so deps/lib/libskgxpg.so deps/lib/libskgxpr.so; do objdump -T $i | head; done

deps/lib/libskgxp11.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000380c l    d  .init  00000000              .init
00003b90 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
00008cc4 l    d  text.unlikely  00000000              text.unlikely
000a719c l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
000a71c0 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
000bbe80 l    d  .eh_frame      00000000              .eh_frame

deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000ca0 l    d  .init  00000000              .init
00000d18 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
00000e04 l    d  text.unlikely  00000000              text.unlikely
00001618 l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
00001640 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
0000188c l    d  .eh_frame      00000000              .eh_frame

deps/lib/libskgxpd.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000ca0 l    d  .init  00000000              .init
00000d18 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
00000e04 l    d  text.unlikely  00000000              text.unlikely
00001618 l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
00001640 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
0000188c l    d  .eh_frame      00000000              .eh_frame

deps/lib/libskgxpg.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000380c l    d  .init  00000000              .init
00003b90 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
00008cc4 l    d  text.unlikely  00000000              text.unlikely
000a719c l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
000a71c0 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
000bbe80 l    d  .eh_frame      00000000              .eh_frame

deps/lib/libskgxpr.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000380c l    d  .init  00000000              .init
00003b90 l    d  .text  00000000              .text
00008cc4 l    d  text.unlikely  00000000              text.unlikely
000a719c l    d  .fini  00000000              .fini
000a71c0 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
000bbe80 l    d  .eh_frame      00000000              .eh_frame
```

I'm scratching my head wondering why I can't link the libskgxp11.so, and what is the relationship between this group of 5 libs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, here are some command sequences I ran to get the list of problem functions and track down the libs:

```
# Get what project needs
make run-tests 2>&1 | grep -Po '(?<=undefined reference to ).*' | tr -d "\`'" | sort -u > undefined.txt

# Complete content of undefined.txt
skgxpcdel
skgxpcini_with_stats
skgxpcon_with_stats
skgxpdis
skgxpdmpctx
skgxpdmpobj
skgxp_get_epid
skgxpgettabledef
skgxpmmap
skgxpnetmappush
skgxppost
skgxprqhi
skgxpsz
skgxptrace
skgxpunmap
skgxpveri
skgxpvrpc
skgxpwait

# Get what deps provide, for comparison to what project needs
(for i in deps/lib/*.so;do objdump -TC $i | grep -E '^...............F';done) | grep -v '[*]UND[*]' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort -u > have.txt

# First few lines of have.txt
_A_BSafeError
AddCRLBerToList
add_error_table
afidrv
AHChooseRandomConstructor2
AHSecretCBCConstructor2
AHSecretCBCPadConstructor2
AI_AES_CBC

# See what is common between what project needs and what deps provide
comm -12 have.txt undefined.txt > left.txt

# A diff of undefined.txt and left.txt indicates they are identical

# Get what deps provide, in a way searchable by a person
(for i in deps/lib/*.so;do echo "====$i"; objdump -TC $i | grep -E '^...............F';done) | grep -v '[*]UND[*]' | awk '{print $NF}' > have-files.txt

# Here's a sample of first two shared libs and some of their funcs, from have-files.txt
====deps/lib/libagfw11.so
clsagfw_get_check_type
clsagfw_exit
clsagfw_get_attrvalue
====deps/lib/libagtsh.so
naecsn
lmsapbn
kokogtv

# for each func left, try to find lib that contains it
(for i in `cat left.txt`;do echo $i; for j in deps/lib/*.so;do (objdump -TC $j | grep -E '^...............F' | grep -v '[*]UND[*]' | grep -q $i) && echo "  $j"; done; done) 2>&1 | more

# Output for first two missing funcs:

skgxpcdel
  deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
skgxpcini_with_stats
  deps/lib/libskgxp11.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpcompat.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpd.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpg.so
  deps/lib/libskgxpr.so
```

Comment: This error message doesn't seem to come from gcc. Are  you getting it when trying to *run* your program?

Comment: If this is a runtime error it looks like the app can not find the library. Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Uggh. I missed the fact that Make was building fine, and complains when running it. I'll work on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Yup, got it working in the sense I now get an oracle error connecting when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

As helpfully suggested in the comments, the problem was occurring trying to run the program. I just needed to use the env command to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the deps/lib dir where all the shared libs are stored:

```
run-tests: $(test_target)
    env "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=deps/lib:$$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" $(test_target)
```

Thanks.